# Good implementation/support for java.util.concurrent.Flow.Processor<T,R>

Tags: reactive-programming, java-9, project-reactor, reactive-streams, java-flow

Recently, I found a good support for Publisher by projectreactor.io:

```
Flux.create(fluxSink -> {
           for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            fluxSink.next(i);
           fluxSink.complete();
        })
                .map(...)
                .subscribe(...);
```

**Is there any good support for Proccessor?**
I mean something like or simular:

```
XXX process = new XXX((inputValue, output) -> {
    if(inputValue == 0)
       output.error();
    else
       output.next(inputValue);
});

publisher.subscribe(process);  
process.subscribe(...);
```

If not, how can I implement my own or why I cannot do this?

**Update 1:**

After discussion (see comments) it appeared that in my use case I need use `flatMap` (see answer), my question was Good implementation of processor by this I meant some functionality that if it's fails I able to take control and emit error instead. I think `flatMap` will give you quite enough functionality. In my case I used:

```
        import org.jsoup.Jsoup;

        Flux.just("url")
            .flatMap(url -> {
                try {
                    Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
                    return Flux.just(document);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    return Flux.error(e);
                }
            })
            .subscribe();
```

Comment: Is Java 9 a requirement in this case? If so, there is a prototype library of mine called Reactive4JavaFlow which has [`Processor`](https://github.com/akarnokd/Reactive4JavaFlow#processors-hot-sources) support you can look into. In general, writing processors can get quite complicated.

Comment: Yes, it's about Java 9.

Comment: What is your use case and why do you think you need a processor to do it?

Comment: For ex. I have some urls and I want to map them to html or json content (get url -> request -> parse content -> output content). If any error occur, I want to signal to subscribers (error) and stop processing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what you described of your use case, I don't expect you really require a `Processor`. Rather, use `flatMap` to trigger the asynchronous URL fetches. `flatMap`, like all Reactive Streams operators, will default to stopping immediately in case of error.

The only part where you might require a processor is to generate the `Flux<URL>` **if you don't know the URLs in advance** (otherwise, a `Flux.fromIterable` or `Flux.just(...)` would do just fine).

If you need to dispatch the result(s) to multiple `Subscriber` without re-triggering the requests, have a look at `publish().connect()` and/or `cache()`.

Comment: I just checked it, Yeah, you're right, flatMap is good for my use case :)

Answer (score 3):

You're probably looking for **[`SubmissionPublisher`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/SubmissionPublisher.html)** which seems similar to the **[`Flux`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html)** implementation in reactor:

> A `Flow.Publisher` that asynchronously issues submitted (non-null)
>   items to current subscribers until it is closed. Each current
>   subscriber receives newly submitted items in the same order unless
>   drops or exceptions are encountered. Using a `SubmissionPublisher`
>   allows item generators to act as compliant reactive-streams Publishers
>   relying on drop handling and/or blocking for flow control.

***Note***: A custom sample `Flow.Processor` is shared in the link which can be further customised to handle `onError` and `consume` method implementation as required for your use case.

Comment: Could you give any example how to implement or use it as processor? Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on what you want to do.

Most of the methods on `Flux` create such processors and just return them as a `Flux` making sure they subscribe in the correct way to the upstream `Flux`.

So if your `Processor` should just emit an event for each one it receives, but a different one `map` is your simple way to create your `Processor`. If it creates multiple (or no) event for each event received use `flatMap` and so on.

You can create even more complex ones by chaining those methods. 
I'd expect 99% of the use cases to be handled this way just fine.

If that is not sufficient, consider the various overloads of `subscribe` where you can use `Consumer` to handle elements of a `Flux` as well as state changes like error, completion and subscription. And you can combine those with, among others with `Flux.create(fluxSink -> ...)` to construct pretty flexible `Processors`.

Comment: I just comment it belong question after you answered "I have some urls and I want to map them to html or json content (get url -> request -> parse content -> output content). If any error occur, I want to signal to subscribers (error) and stop processing." so if I use map or flatMap I cannot stop my processing(signal error) if error happen. Do you know how can I make it by using Flex.just(WebPage).map(retrieveUrls).anyProcessorXXXToRequest Urls().map(maptToWords).subscribe(...)

Comment: if the function inside map throws an exception the Flux will signal an error with that exception. So it pretty much does what you want, right?

Comment: same for flatMap (and really (almost?) all operators on Flux)